Visual Studio: I chose rebase dev onto main, not sure what this did
Given:
Visual Studio 2022
Git for Windows
I was in my dev branch. Inside Visual Studio and Manage Git Branches I selected rebase dev onto main. I'm not exactly sure what that did, but there are ghost looking folders in my main branch now from the dev branch. I thought I would have to at least commit something after the option, but it seems like it pushed something to the origin in Github.
What exactly happened when I chose to rebase dev onto main?


Rebase will not perform a push. You would have had to have pushed or synced separately. Why do you believe it was pushed?

Getting a couple of steps ahead from what @TTT is asking: do not rebase long-lived branches (like dev, master, etc) unless you know what you are doing.

Also, do you simply want to understand what happened, or are you trying to recover something? Typically branches named dev and main would be considered shared branches, and therefore should never be rebased. (Instead you would only rebase personal topic or feature branches.) Is the dev branch one that you actually intend to rebase, or was it accidental and now you wish to know what you did, and possibly undo that? (Looks like @eftshift0 beat me to saying this. I'll leave this as it has additional questions included...)
